# How to get Rid of Duplicate Keys in Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, sql

I keep on getting the error: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: '@QueryID'  Key being added: '@QueryID'. I did some research on this and it tells me that I'm inserting duplicate keys into a dictionary object. Dictionary objects in .Net can only have unique keys. I don't know how to get rid of duplicate keys.

```
class Program
{
   private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    static void Main()
    {
        EMMADatabase db = new EMMADatabase(""); //set string to pass in based on App.config


        try
        {
            Hashtable Parameters = new Hashtable();
            //Parameters.Add("@UserCredentials", UserCredentials);

            DataTable result = db.Query("exec Metrics_ETL.dbo.uspDetermineQueriesToRunBasedOnSchedules", Parameters);
            DataTable QueriesToRun = db.Query("select QueryID from Metrics_ETL.dbo.QueriesToRun", Parameters);

            foreach(DataRow row in QueriesToRun.Rows)
            {
                Hashtable QueryParameters = new Hashtable();
                Parameters.Add("@QueryID", row["QueryID"]);
                DataTable QueryDetails = db.Query("select QueryID, Query, ObjectID, DataSourceID, DatabaseName, ServerName, ServerType, UserName, Password from Metrics_ETL.dbo.Queries where QueryID = @QueryID", Parameters);

                //log.Info(row["QueryID"]);
                //Console.WriteLine(row["QueryID"]);

                //create datasource - query datasource - get data into a datatable

                //write datatable to csv with correct filename (OR maybe C# can write to Excel)
            }



        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

---

I think this is where the @QueryID value is added, but wasn't sure. I am a beginner to programming so I am very noob at this. Any suggestion would greatly be appreciated.

```
 private DataTable QueryToDataTable(string QueryString, Hashtable Parameters)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (new Impersonator("svc-emma-admin", "1dc", "618MId}QM"))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(QueryString, DBConnection);
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 120;

            foreach (DictionaryEntry Parameter in Parameters)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add((string)Parameter.Key, SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                cmd.Parameters[(string)Parameter.Key].Value = Parameter.Value;
            }

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you test for the presence of the key in your dictionary - if it exists, either don't add it, or update it, if it doesn't exist, add the value

Comment: You're calling this *unconditionally* in your loop: `Parameters.Add("@QueryID", row["QueryID"]);`. On the second iteration, that is *bound* to throw an exception. How did you expect it not to? Did you mean to use `QueryParameters` instead of `Parameters`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've created a single `Hashtable` outside your loop, then one on every iteration *inside* your loop. However, you're unconditionally adding to the single "outer" hashtable within the loop, so on the second iteration it's bound to fail.

You're then ignoring the "inner" hashtable entirely.

I suspect you want to get rid of the "outer" hashtable, and just use the "inner" one (`QueryParameters`) when both adding the parameter and specifying the parameters for the query.

As an aside:

- I would strongly recommend using generic collections - in this case probably a `Dictionary<string, object>`. Non-generic collections are so 2004.
- Parameters and local variables are conventionally `camelCased`, e.g. `queryParameters`, not `QueryParameters`
- You currently have an "N+1 selects" problem - you should try to perform the whole query in one go with a join, if at all possible.

Comment: I got rid of the "outer" hastable and have just the "inner" one. However, it still give me the same error. Do I need to Clear() any passed in "queryParamters" first before adding a new dictionary key value?

Comment: @user3882842: If you're still creating a new instance on each iteration, you really shouldn't get that error. You *are* still creating a new instance each time, right? (The `Hashtable QueryParameters = new Hashtable();` line still needs to be inside the loop.)

Comment: Thank you all! With ya'll's help, I was able to solve the problem by using the inside parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an error here:

```
Hashtable QueryParameters = new Hashtable();
Parameters.Add("@QueryID", row["QueryID"]);
DataTable QueryDetails = db.Query("...", Parameters);
```

You just created a new hashtable, QueryParameters, but you're not using it at all.  Instead you're adding your QueryID parameter to the Parameters hashtable, not the QueryParameters hashtable.  Since this line of code gets executed for every row it'll crash on the second iteration.

You can fix the issue by either using QueryParameters instead of Parameters (for the next line and also the following line). Or, you can remove the QueryParameters object completely and just reuse your Parameters object:

```
// Hashtable QueryParameters = new Hashtable();
Parameters.Clear();
Parameters.Add("@QueryID", row["QueryID"]);
```